# Creating QList of multiple object types

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qlist

I need to make multiple instances of various class types (classA, classB, classC), and store then in a single list.  Is is possible to create these objects dynamically and then add them to a single QList?  Something like:

```
QList<QObject> mylist;
mylist.append(classA());
mylist.append(classB());
mylist.append(classC());
```

This won't compile because the objects are not of type QObject.  I could static_cast them to QObject, but will I be able to typeid.name() to determine their origical types?  (To cast them back later)?

I found an example [here](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17106) of using a QList< QVariant >, but the compiler complains that:

> error: no matching function for call to 'QVariant::QVariant(classA&)'

for this code:

```
QList<QVariant> mylist;
mylist.append(QVariant(tempObj));
```

---

Update:

I got it compiling by creating the object during the append operation, AND using ::fromValue.

```
mylist.append(QVariant::fromValue(ClassA(1,2,3)));
```

Not sure this is right.  1 - will this cause a memory leak/problem creating the object in the append statement?  2 - why would I need ::fromValue to make this work?  (Does this just make a second copy of the object?)

I put a qDebug in my constructors, and I see that my constructor with parameters is called twice, then the copy constructor is called once, and the default (no parameters) constructor is never called.  I don't understand that...

Comment: Why not just use a standard container such as `std::list<QObject*>` or `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Object>>`, since the objects are not `QObject`s?

Comment: I see no ways for a possible memory leak. QList will take ownership of the object.

Comment: You need to use fromValue because the compiler will fail to find an overload of `QList::append` that takes a `ClassA`.

Comment: Yeah, this is case where you want c++11 move semantics to cut down on the unnecessary copies. I am not sure but I don't think Qt is doing any move operations here. The code looks right.

Comment: ok - I understand why fromValue is needed now.  But why are 3 constructors called, and is something being lost on the heap/other?

Comment: You are not using the heap (there are no new calls). You are allocating objects on the stack. They are unnamed meaning they are temporaries that "disappear" as soon as the statement finishes. ClassA constructor gets called once when you invoke it with ClassA(1,2,3). That returns a temporary that fromValue makes a copy of. That puts us at 1 constructor and 1 copy constructor. I am not sure what QList does but presumably its responsible for that final call to constructor that it makes when it "owns" the object. If you have move semantics you don't have to make so many unnecessary copies.

Comment: I'm deviating a bit from the question, but: my list will be a class member, and a method will append the new object to the list as above.  When the method exits (and the object was created on the stack), will that corrupt what it in my Qlist?  Will that object be deallocated?  Should I create the classA using 'new'?  (then I'll have to break the code above)

Comment: "When the method exits (and the object was created on the stack), will that corrupt what it in my Qlist?" -- No because QList makes a *copy* of the temporary (which is why it invokes your constructor). The temporary WILL go away but QList has its own copy to hold onto. QList's copy will be destroyed when the QList is destroyed.

Comment: Was I able to help you? If so, could you leave me the best answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `QVariant` which can hold any number of different types: [QVariant API](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvariant.html)

To use `QVariant` with a custom type you need to register it with the metatype system: [QMetaType](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html) This means using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass)` [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)

QVariant is designed for holding objects of different types, and is used in all sorts of Qt conventions when the programmer wants to pass around user-defined types through Qt's interfaces when Qt itself has no way of knowing which type the programmer wants to use.

To convert back to the original type use a combination of `QVariant::canConvert()` and `QVariant::value()`:

```
QVariant v;

MyCustomStruct c;
if (v.canConvert<MyCustomStruct>())
    c = v.value<MyCustomStruct>();

v = 7;
int i = v.value<int>();                        // same as v.toInt()
QString s = v.value<QString>();                // same as v.toString(), s is now "7"
MyCustomStruct c2 = v.value<MyCustomStruct>(); // conversion failed, c2 is empty
```

Your custom type must provide:

1. a public default constructor,
2. a public copy constructor, and
3. a public destructor.

The following `Message` class is an example of an acceptable custom type for use in `QVariant`

```
class Message
{
 public:
   Message();
   Message(const Message &other);
   ~Message();

   Message(const QString &body, const QStringList &headers);

   QString body() const;
   QStringList headers() const;

 private:
   QString m_body;
   QStringList m_headers;
};
```

---

You could also declare your own "meta-type wrapper" that holds a type and a description of a type. The simplest example:

```
template <typename T>
class AnyType
{
public:
  enum THE_TYPE { MT_INT, MT_STRING };

  AnyType(T value, THE_TYPE type) : value(value), type(type) { }
  THE_TYPE getType() { return type; }
  T getValue() { return value; }

private:
  T value;
  THE_TYPE type;
}
```

Comment: I just found this around time of your posting...I like the QVariant idea, but how do I determine the original type/class name of each item on the list?

Comment: To clarify, once the objects are on the list, I won't know what their original types were.  How do I detect the original types (class names) etc. so I can static cast them back and use them?

Comment: I've updated my question, QList< QVariant > seems like the way to go.  But appending to this list gives a compiler error.  Can you add a code example for that?

Comment: Did you register your type with the metatype system

Comment: Yes I have a Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(classA) after the class in the classA.h file

Comment: I just added those (a public default constructor, a public copy constructor, and a public destructor) - but same error.  There must be something missing, there error message (above) looks like copy constructor missing, but it's there

Comment: Maybe try posting the type.

Comment: getting closer - see my update above.  I got it running using an example found online, but I'm not convinced its right (or I dont understand why it is)

Answer (score 2):

> I could static_cast them to QObject

No, you couldn't!  And this is illegal:

```
QList<QObject> mylist;
```

QObjects have a notion of identity, and are non-copyable types.  You have to manipulate them by pointer, and that would be a list of QObject values.

But speaking more generally (about seeking to get around this kind of thing with casting)...a QList and other templated containers specifically allocate an amount of memory for the object type they are parameterized with.  So a `QList<A>` at the implementation level has only enough storage per item to store `sizeof(A)`, while a `QList<B>` can only hold items that are `sizeof(B)`.

So first of all: if you cast an *object* vs. casting a *pointer* then you really do lose information you can't get back...if you can even get the compiler to let you do it.  And secondly: you need to be careful even if you have a slot that holds pointers to cast to them to a "punned type" and back again due to various pitfalls which come from doing so.  Despite pointers to different types being the same size as pointers, you've got to reckon with things like the [Strict Aliasing Requirement](http://dbp-consulting.com/StrictAliasing.pdf).

You can work around this with something like the `QVariant` as suggested by @snowandotherjoys.  If you wanted to be more "standard" you might look at [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html).

But it's often said that a case requiring some kind of run-time-typing like this may mean you need to take a second look at the design.  If classA and classB and classC are so different that they have no interface in common, what is it that makes putting them in a single collection that is compelling?  What can you usefully do with a collection of things that have nothing in common?  While these cases *do* come up (and motivate the existence of variants) it's valuable to step back and ask if you really do have one of those cases.